# Convert a "test" correctly from POSIX sh to old plain bourne shell

Tags: shell, unix, sh

On an old Solaris that only has plain bourne shell, I haven't been able to correctly translate a simple test such as:

```
[ -d '/export/home/mydir' -o ! -e '/export/home/mydir' -a -d $(dirname '/export/home/mydir') ]
```

...as is supported under modern POSIX shells such as ash, bash, ksh, &c.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: The `$()` expansion might not work, try backticks instead.

Comment: Tried [ -d '/export/home/mydir' -o ! -e '/export/home/mydir' -a -d `dirname '/export/home/mydir'` ] but got "unknown operator '/export/home/mydir'".

Comment: The backticks aren't showing in the previous comment.

Comment: "old Solaris" may not have `dirname`... For that matter, what exactly is the point of `-d $(dirname <somedir>)`? Why not just `-d <somedir>`?

Comment: Old Solaris has `dirname`; that's not the problem.  `$()` is a problem and requires back-ticks.   I'll need to see what replaces `!`.

Comment: BTW, that's (bad) POSIX sh, not bash. (The POSIX standard explicitly describes `-a` and `-o` as obsolescent; they're not intended for use in modern scripts -- but anyhow, there aren't any bash extensions at all in your original expression).

Comment: _[…time passes…]_ 7th Edition `test` supports `!` as negation, so Bourne shell should too.  You might need to use parentheses `'('` and `')'` to group terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With portable shell scripting, try avoiding using `-a` and `-o` for `and` and `or`.  Additionally, as others have commented, `$()` expansion may not be available, but backticks will be.

Try this instead:

```
if [ -d '/export/home/mydir' ] || [ ! -e '/export/home/mydir' ] && [ -d `dirname '/export/home/mydir'` ]; then
```

If `[` isn't available, you may need to use `test` instead of `[` and remove the closing `]`s.

For reference, here is a guide on [writing portable shell scripts](http://sites.harvard.edu/~lib113/reference/unix/portable_scripting.html).

Comment: Should probably add double quotes around the backtick, just in case we get called with IFS=/ or have a directory name containing whitespace...

Comment: Great! Works like a charm ... only thing is, supposing I'm forced to use just "test" (no square brackets) how should I go about grouping the terms (among the ANDs and the ORs)?

Comment: OK, verified that parentheses work as usual, so no problem using test. Thanks.

Comment: @RoccoRossi - If this answer helped solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) using the check mark under the voting arrows.  Thank you!

Comment: @RoccoRossi FYI, you would just replace each `[` with `test`, and delete the corresponding `]`: `[ -d '/some/dir' ]` is equivalent to `test -d '/some/dir'`. The `&&` and `||` are not part of the `test` commands; they are shell operators that join separate commands into a list.